# Returning # Of Items from ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I am trying to obtain the amount of objects returned from the ParseQueryAdapter and put them in a TextView to show the user the amount loaded.

I tried something like this, but keeps displaying 0 even though items are loaded into the listview fine.

```
bookSalesAdapter = new BookSalesAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(bookSalesAdapter);

    int bookSalesAmount = bookSalesAdapter.getCount();
    String bookSales = Integer.toString(bookSalesAmount);
    TextView salesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_bookSalesAmount);
    salesAmount.setText(bookSales);
```

Any ideas how I would go about grabbing the amount of items using the ParseQueryAdapter rather then running another query?

This didn't seem to work from the activity with listview.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener.html).

You can write code to run after the objects have been loaded by the adapter. From there, you should be able to fetch the count.

Before you call setListAdapter():

```
bookSalesAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<Book>() {
    @Override
    public void onLoading() {}

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(List<Event> events, Exception e) {
        // Access the item count through the adapter's getCount() and update your UI...
    }
});
```